# Detect IsAlive on an IObservable

Tags: system.reactive, code-golf

I'm writing a function `IsAlive` to take an `IObservable<T>`, and a timespan, and return an  `IObservable<bool>` The canonical use case is to detect if a streaming server is still sending data.

I've come up with the following solution for it, but feel it's not the most clear as to how it works.

```
public static IObservable<bool> IsAlive<T>(this IObservable<T> source, 
                                           TimeSpan timeout, 
                                           IScheduler sched)
{
    return source.Window(timeout, sched)
                 .Select(wind => wind.Any())
                 .SelectMany(a => a)
                 .DistinctUntilChanged();
}
```

Does anyone have a better approach?

FYI -
Here are the unit tests and existing approaches that I've tried: https://gist.github.com/997003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
public static IObservable<bool> IsAlive<T>(this IObservable<T> source, 
                                           TimeSpan timeout, 
                                           IScheduler sched)
{
    return source.Buffer(timeout, 1, sched)
                 .Select(l => l.Any())
                 .DistinctUntilChanged();
}
```

This approach makes semantic sense, too. Every time an item comes in, it fills the buffer and then true is passed along. And every timeout, an empty buffer will be created and false will be passed along.

**Edit:**

This is why the buffer-1 approach is better than windowing:

```
var sched = new TestScheduler();
var subj = new Subject<Unit>();

var timeout = TimeSpan.FromTicks(10);

subj
    .Buffer(timeout, 1, sched)
    .Select(Enumerable.Any)
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Buffer(timeout, 1): " + x));

subj
    .Window(timeout, sched)
    .Select(wind => wind.Any())
    .SelectMany(a => a)
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Window(timeout): "+x));

sched.AdvanceTo(5);
subj.OnNext(Unit.Default);
sched.AdvanceTo(16);
```

yields:

```
Buffer(timeout, 1): True
Window(timeout): True
Buffer(timeout, 1): False
```

To be specific, the window is open for the whole timeout and doesn't close and reset as soon as an item comes in. This is where the buffer limit of 1 comes into play. As soon as an item comes in, the buffer *and its timer* get restarted.

I could re-implement my buffer as a window, as buffer's implementation *is* a window, but a) I think buffer makes better semantic sense and b) I don't have to SelectMany. Scott's Select and SelectMany could be combined into a single SelectMany(x => x.Any()), but I can avoid the entire lambda and specify the Enumerable.Any method group, which will bind faster (trivial) anyway.

Comment: This is basically the same as the OP except using `Buffer` instead of `Window` (the former is implemented using the latter)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
source.Select(_ => true)
    .Timeout(timeout, sched)
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Catch<bool, TimeoutException>)(ex => Observable.Return(false));
```

Comment: doesn't work in the case of heartbeats that start after the timeout time has passed has occurred.

Comment: If you `Concat` the error back onto the `Return`, you can follow up with a `Retry`. I'd then probably wrap the whole thing in a `Publish(x => { ... })` to support cold sources.

Comment: I'd also move the `DistinctUntilChanged` to after the `Publish` or at least the `Catch`, otherwise you might get false duplicates.